# "2x"/zoomed resources in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

With 3.2, honeycomb devices now have the option to have an application "Stretch to fill screen". In my opinion, my apps look better in this mode than in the regular zoom mode. I know all about Fragments and how I could use them to fill the space with more (useful) information, but the size of the android tablet market just doesn't justify that expense right now.

On iPads, you can make the 2x/stretched experience look much better by providing higher-density resources. The android resource system would seem to make it a no-brainer to make "stretch to fill screen" an acceptable experience for the time being. Is there any way to do it?

**Edit:** for example, can I put my resources in some kind of "res/drawable-2xdpi" folder to have my app automatically stretched, layout-wise, but use the higher-res images.

**Edit:** **Zoom** to fill screen is the mode in Android 3.2 where images are made larger to fill the larger available space on a tablet, and which is analagous to the 2x mode on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

[drawable-xhdpi](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) contains high res graphics for Tablets.

2x won't work since Android supports more than one resolution/aspect-ratio compared to the iPad.

Comment: I know that Android supports many resolutions. What I am looking for is an easy/cost-effective way to provide higher-resolutions resources in the 3.2 "stretch to fill screen mode" so that my apps can look good on a tablet without me having to completely re-engineer them. (I am personally all-in on Android, but I know that iOS provides this functionality. The Android resource framework provides a perfect framework for doing this, I just want to know if there is some way to take advantage of it.)

Comment: As mentioned `drawable-xhdpi` is the place for tablet quality resources: http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by putting your larger drawables in drawable-large and drawable-xlarge, these will then be used for tablet devices.

All tablets released so far are mdpi so just dropping stuff in drawable-large/xlarge should work.